# bootstrap tooltip is not working on button tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

**Update**

The fiddle example is working, my bad. However it's not working on my test website, and I made a quick example on my website.

[Link][1]

Typing 'medicine' and press button 'go'. If you hover over the button on the top-right corner, `tooltip` seems not working, but the 'add' `a` tag works.

This is my javascript code:

```
    $("body").tooltip({
    placement: 'top',
    selector: 'button.resize',
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: 'message'
});
```

<del>Here is an example of my code: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q5sZ/4/).</del>

<del>I made a `tooltip` for an `a` tag, which works. However, I did the exactly same thing to an `button` and the code seems broken. I have spent several hours on this issue, but still no cure.</del>

<del>P.S. The button is generated dynamically in my application, so I used `selector`.</del>

Comment: You have to post relevant code in question, not just posting a jsFiddle link

Comment: I do see the tooltip, what's wrong?

Comment: @haim770 Don't you find it weird that it works only on the second button given the first and second exactly look alike?

Comment: Ya, unclear what is the issue, even after checking the jsFiddle...

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz It works on both, just the placement option of tooltip is not relevant here, so looks like a logic issue indeed: http://jsfiddle.net/9Q5sZ/5/

Comment: @A.Wolff Ah, so that's the culprit:D

Comment: @A.Wolff, I updated the question, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work for the first button as well, but since the `placement` is set to `top` you don't see it because it's being rendered outside the viewport. Try this:

```
$("body").tooltip({
    placement: 'right',
    selector: 'button.resize',
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: 'message'
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q5sZ/6/)

**Update (as per your comment):**

The problem is that you're calling `$('body').tooltip()` twice. You can either try:

```
//add definition tooltip
$("body").tooltip({
    placement: 'right',
    selector: 'a.add',
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: posts.addDefinition
});

//resize tooltip
$("html").tooltip({
    placement: 'top',
    selector: 'button.resize',
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: 'message'
});
```

Or expand the selector to include both, and use a function to determine the `title`:

```
$("body").tooltip({
    placement: 'right',
    selector: 'a.add, button.resize',
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: function() {
        return this.title; // insert your custom logic here
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @haim770, I updated my problem. My fiddle code didn't present the issue correctly. Sorry about that.